# How to display consistent datetime label formats in xAxis using highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to graph my data fetched from an ajax call. And, as such I don't know how to configure datetime label formats in `xAxis` to display in a consistent format (eg. **10 May 2017 08:00 pm**, **10 May 2017 12:00 pm**, **10 May 2017 16:00 pm**, **10 May 2017 20:00 pm**, **11 May 2017 12:00 am** and **11 May 2017 04:00 am**).  This assume a one day range of data from 10 May 2017 to 11 May 2017.

In the red box (screenshot below), `xAxis` display these values 08:00, 12:00, 16:00, 20:00, 11 May 2017 12:00 am and 04:00, which I don't want this kind of format.

[image: chart]

This is my highchart code

```
myChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift',
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'left',
        itemDistance: 10,
        borderWidth: 0,
        itemMarginTop: 0,
        itemMarginBottom: 0,
        padding: 20
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                format: '{y}'
            },
            allowPointSelect: false
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        //tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
        labels: {
            rotation: -65,
            style: {
                fontSize: '9px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        },
        crosshair: true,
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            //month: '%b \'%y',
            //day: '%e. %b',
            //year: '%Y'
            day: '%d %b %Y %I:%M %P'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineColor: '#DDDDDD',
        gridLineWidth: 0.5
    },
    tooltip: {
        positioner: function () {
            return {
                x: this.chart.plotLeft,
                y: this.chart.plotTop
            }
        },
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function (tooltip) {
            var value = Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', new Date(this.x));
            const header = `<span style="font-size: 8px">${value}</span><br/>`;
            let body = this.points.reduce((body, p) => body + `<small><font color="${p.series.color}"><strong>${p.series.name}</strong></font>: <strong>${p.y}</strong></small><br/>`, '');
            const plotLines = tooltip.chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands;

            if (plotLines.length) {
                var plotValue = Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', new Date(plotLines[0].options.value));
                body += `<small>Plot line: <strong>${plotValue}</strong></small>`
            }
            return header + body;
        },
        shared: true,
        valueDecimals: 2,
        followPointer: true,
        shadow: false,
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)'
    },
    series: [{
        name: xtitle,
        data: dataseries
    }]
});
```

I tried several combination of `dateTimeLabelFormats` but I can't achieve the result that I want.

I have posted a sample fiddle link for my scenario [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2z2wzje/12/)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dateTimeLabelFormats](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats) for `xAxis` Label

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/q2z2wzje/13/)

Code Extract

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        //tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
        labels: {
            rotation: -65,
            style: {
                fontSize: '9px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        },
        crosshair: true,
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          second: '%d %b %Y <br/> %H:%M:%S %P',
      }
    },
```

Comment: thanks much for updating my fiddle.  What is the difference between using `day` and `second` unit in `dateTimeLabelFormats`? Does the configured formats matter based on the unit?

Comment: yes configured formats matter based on the unit. As it is explained in the [link](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats)

Comment: that's great, makes sense.  Thank you.